# Visual studio 2017, resharper - broken indentation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resharper

For whatever reason the line indentation broke for Visual Studio for me, but only for .NET Core projects (any other projects have correct setup). No matter what I put in the settings its always 2 spaces even though scaffolded components still get generated with 4.

Which ends up with:

```
public SomeClass 
{
public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

I also tried changing it in resharper but it also doesn't seem to work.

[image: Resharper Window]

This is literally driving me nuts. Anyone else had this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you encounter this issue, in my case it was .editorconfig file that had settings, which were overriding the configuration of both visual studio, and resharper. The file can be localized either in your solution folder, or more often in the folder which contains your package.json if you're using any framework like angular for your frontend.

```
# Editor configuration, see http://editorconfig.org
root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.md]
max_line_length = off
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

This has already been reported to Microsoft by other developers but they don't consider it a bug.

Comment: It is not a bug that editorconfig is overriding the configuration in Visual Studio and ReSharper, that is entirely by design.

Comment: A editorconfig file should only be used for the folder it is in and subfolders. If you place the editorconfig into a subfolder, it should only be used for that subfolder and subfolders of it. Are you saying that when placed into a subfolder, it still changes the behavior on the outside of that folder?

Comment: Yeah, thats what people in MS say, that its by design. Which doesn't change the fact its completely misleading and you have an army of people complaining about it. Answering the second question, its actually placed 2 folders above the .sln file.

Comment: I am not going to debate this at length here in this comment thread but I don't understand why you think it is misleading, or what it is that is misleading. The whole purpose of editorconfig is explicitly to override the editor user settings, to ensure consistent file handling and formatting among people working on the same project. This is not something Microsoft or Jetbrains cooked up. If you don't want what editorconfig does, remove the editorconfig file.